# Does MOB works for panel data in R?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, party, longitudinal

I am trying to use model-based recursive partitioning(MOB) package partykit in `R` to do segmentation, but my data is panel data which has a date and a couple of other columns as well.
Here is an example

```
id date    col1 col2 clo3
1. 200910  ...
1. 200911
1. 200912
2. 200910
2. 200911
2. 200912
```

So Instead of using logistic regression. I am using `plm` package in R to do the modeling. Because I do not want the same id clustered to different clusters. However, when I fit in the regression function to MOB, then it gives me the following error.

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')
```

seems that MOB can not extract the log-likelihood from the regression model.
I am not 100% sure if that's the reason, and if it is possible to run a panel regression model in the MOB.

Comment: Hi @user14538, welcome to Stackoverflow! You will increase the likelihood that someone answers your question if you provide a minimum reproducible example; for more information about it, take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example